# Private Key not installed on this mac

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, iphone-developer-program

I am a team member of a developer account, obviously without admin/agent rights, and I am trying to create a provisioning profile for distribution. I already asked the account owner to create a certificate of his own and use it to create a provisioning profile for distribution with it, but when I try to use them it tells me that the private key for the current application is not installed on this mac. Now the question is, why can't I use his certificate/provisioning profile to archive for apple store? Do I need admin rights for this? Or do I need to create a certificate from my machine to sign the code?

Comment: you need the private key. without a private key you cannot sign anything.

Comment: if the admin created certificate for you on his mac, request him to export the certificate from keychain and send them to you. It will contain both private and public keys. Else you would need to generate your own.

Comment: is it safe for him to do that? I am trying to not offend them

Comment: He sent me the distribution provisioning profile and the certificate (.cer) file that he used to create the provisioning profile with. However, even if I can see his certificate in my keychain access, I cannot get to see "Iphone Distribution" code sign identity.

Comment: What I suspect that is causing me this problem is that I only have member rights and for this reason it cannot use the owner certificate to code sign? If I go in Xcode-> Prefferences->Accounts->and I select the team and click on the lower right corner on the View Details, I can only see IOS Development Signing Identity. If I press the "+" and select "IOS Distribution" I get the error: "An error occurred while requesting a certificate".